# Can I create a Neon distribution that has all the add-on and project information?

Tags: eclipse

Kind of new to the Java development game and I'm wondering if there is a way to create some sort of a profile or distribution of one of our Eclipse Neon IDE configurations.  When a new developer start with my team it takes like three days to get everything installed, configured, and finally up and running.

Is there any way to create a profile or distribution that will speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

A [set of plug-ins can be installed via *Eclipse Marketplace favorites* at once](https://youtu.be/Y0-cO9wZj6w?t=2m19s) and [with the *p2 director* you can build your own Eclipse distribution](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html). But if you also want to configure the Eclipse IDE and run tasks on start-up (e. g. clone a Git repository and import projects from the cloned Git repository), then probably ***[Eclipse Oomph](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer)*** is the right tool for you. Beside *Eclipse Oomph*, there are couple of other [tools to create/maintain a custom Eclipse distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2839987/6505250).